# How to refresh horizontalview in android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, horizontallist

I have 10 section like a tab, but not a tab, it is button.

[image]

if i click Europe, then display data on horizontal view.Data not fixed. eg 10 , if i clicked africa then 25 data will be populated in horizontal view.

How could i do this.

**Note:**
I display data succesfully in first time , when click europe 10 data in to the horizontal view but in second, other buttons then it cannot be display, something went crash. and got this error log.

```
01-13 11:30:18.090: E/AndroidRuntime(3493): java.lang.IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child
01-13 11:30:18.090: E/AndroidRuntime(3493):     at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.addView(HorizontalScrollView.java:213)
```

**[My sample code, where getting error.](http://pastebin.com/a6Vtv25k)**

I just solve adding this line of code.

```
                linlayout.addView(innerYello);

                if(horizontalScrollview.getChildCount()>0){
                    horizontalScrollview.removeAllViews();
                    horizontalScrollview.addView(linlayout);
                }else {
                    horizontalScrollview.addView(linlayout);
                }
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/a6Vtv25k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IllegalStateException: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct
>   child

means you are trying to add more then one view in `HorizontalScrollView` .

In `HorizontalScrollView` we only add one view as a child of `HorizontalScrollView`. so if you want to add more view then use any container view like RelativeLayout,LinearLayout,FrameLayout,... as child  of `HorizontalScrollView` then add other views in container view instead of directly in `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: I have linearlayout in horizontalview. first time data will be add on linearlayout and pupulated in horizontalview. but in second time data also try to add same linearlayout, where already data exist. i think there will be error. but how to solve this, i am so coufused.  i used removeview, but could not work. any idead. how to refresh linearlayout inside the horizontalview.

Comment: @PrAndroid: make sure you are not removing Layout from `HorizontalScrollView` ? so instead of removing Layout remove all views from layout to refresh layout

Comment: @PrAndroid: try it as before adding layout in ScrollView call `horizontalScrollview.removeAllViews();horizontalScrollview.addView(yelloDetailsLinearLayout1);`

Comment: yeah i try, but data will be append previous data. not replaced old data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68707/discussion-between-prandroid-and--k).